# How to install FaceApp to mac?

Tags: iphone, mac, applications, install

How do I install [FaceApp](https://faceapp.com/app) in macOS? Is there anyway to do it without using an iPhone or Android emulator?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FaceApp#Criticism

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the App Store Preview for [FaceApp - AI Face Editor](https://apps.apple.com/app/apple-store/id1180884341?ct=&pt=119065392) it states:

> This app is available only on the App Store for iPhone and iPad.

Also:

> Requires iOS 11.0 or later. Compatible with iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch.

Based on that, I'd say no.